# Spring Security returns 200 OK instead of desired 4xx Internal Server Error in browser client when throwing Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am working on a backend login and user registration app that serves a web application. I am using `spring-security-web-6.0.2`, and when I use postman, my POST requests go through correctly as I expect. However, when I throw an IllegalStateException for trying to register a user which already exists, I expect for Spring to respond with a 500 Internal Server Error, however I am still given a 200 OK.  The following is the associated class which I am referring to and security configuration class: I cannot understand why I am still receiving a 200.

Application Class:

```
package com.akabryan.springproject.appuser;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AppUserService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final static String USER_NOT_FOUND_MSG = "User with email %s not found";

    private final AppUserRepository appUserRepository;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        return appUserRepository.findByEmail(email)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format(USER_NOT_FOUND_MSG, email)));
    }

    public String signUpUser(AppUser appUser) {
        boolean userExists = appUserRepository.findByEmail(appUser.getEmail()).isPresent();

        if (userExists) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Email already taken.");
        }

        String encodedPassword = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(appUser.getPassword());

        appUser.setPassword(encodedPassword);
        
        appUserRepository.save(appUser);
        
        //TODO: Send confirmation token
        
        
        return "Successfully registered";
    }
}
```

The following is the web security configuration:

```
package com.akabryan.springproject.security.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import com.akabryan.springproject.appuser.AppUserService;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final AppUserService appUserService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/api/v*/registration/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin();

        return http.build();
    }

    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        provider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(appUserService);

        return provider;
    }

}
```

Edit: Here is my @RestController Class.

```
package com.akabryan.springproject.registration;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/registration")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RegistrationController {

    private RegistrationService registrationService;

    @PostMapping
    public String register(@RequestBody RegistrationRequest request) {
        return registrationService.register(request);
    }
}
```

Here is what my console logs. Note the first successful registration attempt, and the IllegalStateException that is thrown. Which should induce a 500 Error:

```
This is starting the signup user process.
Hibernate: select nextval('student_sequence')
Hibernate: insert into app_user (app_user_role, email, enabled, first_name, last_name, locked, password, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
User was successfully added to the repo.
Hibernate: select a1_0.id,a1_0.app_user_role,a1_0.email,a1_0.enabled,a1_0.first_name,a1_0.last_name,a1_0.locked,a1_0.password from app_user a1_0 where a1_0.email=?
This is starting the signup user process.
An IllegalStateException should be thrown after this.
2023-04-19T10:35:47.789-04:00 ERROR 23184 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Email already taken.] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Email already taken.
    at com.akabryan.springproject.appuser.AppUserService.signUpUser(AppUserService.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.akabryan.springproject.registration.RegistrationService.register(RegistrationService.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.akabryan.springproject.registration.RegistrationController.register(RegistrationController.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:563) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:631) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:58) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:188) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:174) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Edit 2: The following is the `RegistrationService` class. These seem fine to me but I can't really pinpoint and root cause of my issue from these classes.

```
package com.akabryan.springproject.registration;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.akabryan.springproject.appuser.AppUser;
import com.akabryan.springproject.appuser.AppUserRole;
import com.akabryan.springproject.appuser.AppUserService;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RegistrationService {

    private final AppUserService appUserService;
    private EmailValidator emailValidator;

    public String register(RegistrationRequest request) {

        boolean isValidEmail = emailValidator.test(request.getEmail());

        if (!isValidEmail) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Email is not valid");
        }

        return appUserService.signUpUser(new AppUser(request.getFirstName(), request.getLastName(), request.getEmail(),
                request.getPassword(), AppUserRole.USER));
    }

}
```

Comment: What is does the response body contain for the 200 with an existing email? Can you add some logging to the line above _throw new IllegalStateException("Email already taken.");_ to see that it gets there.

Comment: @JohnWilliams The response body for the 200 with an existing email is actually just the html of my default login page. I edited the post to add the console logs.

Comment: Serving the login page if the the registration call fails is behaviour you have requested in the filterChain. After all the user is not yet authenticated. Using a 4xx error rather than a 5xx error as suggested in the accepted answer may also fix it. If not, try adding “/error” as an antMatchers/permitAll.

Comment: @JohnWilliams Thank you, I think 442 is the most appropriate response. Secondly, adding "/error" as a requestMatcher/permitAll (my version of Spring Boot in this case), fixes it just fine as well which makes sense.

Comment: I think taking the auth requirement off the error page is the correct solution here, not a bunch of 4xx exceptions. Depends if you are serving a browser (error page is better) or an api client (http-4xx is better)

Comment: Definitely the way to go, especially since big tech responds with `200 OK` most of the time and then responds accordingly. I am serving a browser so this is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning a login page when the user registration fails is actually being caused by your `SecurityFilterChain`:

```java
http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/api/v*/registration/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin();
```

The sequence of events is that when the registration fails and exception thrown Spring attempts to take you to the `/error` page. However, `/error` is not `permitAll` so calling it needs an authenticated user so Spring redirects the client to the login page.

To fix this add `/error` as an `antMatchers/permitAll` to the security filter chain.

Also, this sort of error is not a server error (5xx) it’s a client error (an email address being submitted by the client is invalid because it has been used before), so use a 4xx error as suggested in @Phillip’s answer. To do this rather throw a

```java
ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "User with address already exists")
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I did not realize that "/error" was necessary! This fixed it perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Not to be too pedantic about things, but if you are going to use built-in Java exceptions, you may want to consider using the [`IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) over the [`IllegalStateException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) to more closely match the condition your code encounters.  I will do this in my example code.

I think the problem you've encountered is that Spring does not have exception handling configured to catch the `IllegalStateException` and return an HTTP response with an HTTP status code indicating an error.  However, you can implement this yourself.  The easiest way to do this given your example is to catch the exception(s) your service code is throwing within your controller, and then throw a new [`ResponseStatusException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/ResponseStatusException.html) that declares the HTTP status code you want returned:

```java
@PostMapping
public String register(@RequestBody RegistrationRequest request) {
    try {
        return registrationService.register(request);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException|IllegalStateException e) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Registration request cannot be completed.", e)
    }
}
```

You could also take advantage of the [`ResponseStatusExceptionResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/ResponseStatusExceptionResolver.html) to handle resolving exception types into the appropriate HTTP response status.
To do so, simply create custom exceptions within your code base and annotate them with [`ResponseStatus`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseStatus.html) to declare that you want a particular HTTP status code returned when these exceptions are caught by the Spring framework.  For example,

```java
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class DuplicateEmailRegistrationException extends RuntimeException {
    public DuplicateEmailRegistrationException() {
        super();
    }
    public DuplicateEmailRegistrationException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
    public DuplicateEmailRegistrationException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
    public DuplicateEmailRegistrationException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}


@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class InvalidEmailRegistrationException extends RuntimeException {
    public InvalidEmailRegistrationException() {
        super();
    }
    public InvalidEmailRegistrationException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
    public InvalidEmailRegistrationException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
    public InvalidEmailRegistrationException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}
```

Then, instead of throwing `IllegalStateException` or `IllegalArgumentException` within your service classes, you would throw the custom exceptions you created that are specific to the problem encountered.

```java
public String signUpUser(AppUser appUser) {
    boolean userExists = appUserRepository.findByEmail(appUser.getEmail()).isPresent();

    if (userExists) {
        throw new DuplicateEmailRegistrationException("Email already taken.");
    }
    // ...
}
```

If you go this second route, you no longer need to catch and re-throw the `ResponseStatusException` within your controller.

I hope one of these options helps you resolve your issue!

Edit: Updated `HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR` to `HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST` to be more in line with error states being checked in OPs post.

Comment: Great insight and help in finding solution! This actually makes complete sense! I do not know why I was under the assumption that Spring has handling for Java exceptions! I will go the second route which you mentioned as I think this would be the easiest to configure, and would be nice to have custom Exceptions! Thank you for the answer, I am new to Spring, so learning about these nuances are helpful.

Comment: Spring is a wonderful framework, and there are often several ways to accomplish a task.  [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) often has good articles and tutorials.  BTW, I used HTTP error code 500 in my example code, since that's what you asked about, but I think HTTP 400 Bad Request would be more appropriate for the conditions you are checking (`HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST`).  I think I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: I agree, after viewing different Http codes, I think 442 is the most appropriate for the situation. I will also check out Baeldung as well, thank you.